# Merging AndroidManifest.xml Different Android Studio

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio

I tried to Merging the two files, but many of the errors show what is right

Master file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.life.com">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:node="remove" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/ConversationsTheme"
        tools:replace="android:label">
        <service android:name=".services.XmppConnectionService" />
        <receiver android:name=".services.EventReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
                <action android:name="android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.ConversationActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:minWidth="300dp"
            android:minHeight="300dp"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.StartConversationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_start_conversation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="imto" />
                <data android:host="jabber" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="xmpp" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="xmpp" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:host="chat.domain.com" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/i/" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/j/" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.WelcomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MagicCreateActivity"
            android:label="@string/create_account"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.SetPresenceActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/change_presence"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.ChooseContactActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_choose_contact" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.BlocklistActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_block_list" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.ChangePasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/change_password_on_server" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.ManageAccountActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_manage_accounts"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.EditAccountActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.ConferenceDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_conference_details"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.ContactDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contact_details"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.PublishProfilePictureActivity"
            android:label="@string/mgmt_account_publish_avatar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.VerifyOTRActivity"
            android:label="@string/verify_otr"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.ShareWithActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.service.chooser.chooser_target_service"
                android:value=".services.ContactChooserTargetService" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.TrustKeysActivity"
            android:label="@string/trust_omemo_fingerprints"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="de.duenndns.ssl.MemorizingActivity"
            android:theme="@style/ConversationsTheme"
            tools:replace="android:theme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.SettingsActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.life.com.ui.SettingsActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageActivity" />

        <service android:name=".services.ExportLogsService" />
        <service
            android:name=".services.ContactChooserTargetService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_CHOOSER_TARGET_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.chooser.ChooserTargetService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.life.com.files"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The following codes file you want to add and integrate it with the file above
The following file is a file to another project for notifications I want to integrate it the right way
To become all one file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.fcmpush.com"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.fcmpush.com.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.fcmpush.com.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_fcm"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.fcmpush.com.UI.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.fcmpush.com.UI.DailogeNotice"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dialog"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.fcmpush.com.UI.CustomeWebView"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.fcmpush.com.UI.PreferenceActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <service android:name="com.fcmpush.com.Push.FIRInstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.fcmpush.com.Push.FIRMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                <action android:name="com.fcmpush.com.SDK.FCMActivity.NEW_NOTIFICATION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <activity android:name="com.fcmpush.com.Push.FCMActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.fcmpush.com.UI.CategorySelectionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_category_selection"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
        <service android:name="com.fcmpush.com.Push.AlarmReceiver"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.fcmpush.com.Push.AlarmBrodcastReceiver"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
            tools:replace="android:value" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I'm new and I learn and thank you and apologize for any inconvenience

Comment: Helllo @Roanda you have same project or another?if same then how got two menifest file?

Comment: Hello sir @SachinSuthar The second code is for another project :)
You merge files but this AndroidManifest
I have shown a lot of mistakes because I am at fault :)

Comment: that's not possible but if you want to use another  project menifest file directly then add that it own project and then just you have to add that class in your menifest. then you do not getting problem.

Comment: Thanks Mr @SachinSuthar but now  Error:Execution failed for task ':processFreeDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.gms.version@value value=(@integer/google_play_services_version) from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.0] AndroidManifest.xml:20:66-119
 is also present at [io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.7] AndroidManifest.xml:31:13-36 value=(6587000).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:20:9-121 to override.

Comment: remove that metadata if you don't use google map.